# source .bash_profile permission denied

Tags: macos, bash

Mac Os Mavericks

added bin folder to home

added to .bash_profile this:

`export PATH=$PATH;$HOME/bin`

changed owner of .bash_profile to me (paul)

`source  ~/.bash_profile`  generates

`/Users/paul/.bash_profile:4: permission denied: /Users/paul/bin`

`ls -la $HOME/bin`  is

```
 drwxr-xr-x   2 paul  staff    68 Aug 31 08:58 .
 drwxr-xr-x+ 55 paul  staff  1870 Aug 31 09:33 ..
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should grow the habit to quote strings that contain shell variables, or it will continue to bite you.

Comment: @user2719058 although that is true in general, in this case if the  semicolon was quoted there would be a silent failure, as the `$PATH` variable would not be delimited correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write

```
export PATH=$PATH;$HOME/bin
```

you actually have two commands `export PATH=$PATH` (that basically does nothing), and then `$HOME/bin`, which is expanded to `/Users/paul/bin`, and causes an error since you cannot execute a directory.

It should probably be

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
 #               ^
 #               + -------- colon (:) instead of semicolon (;)
```

Comment: that's it ... wont let me check answer for another 5 minutes I'll be back this evening ... thank you!!!!